# Calling JavaScript function from a html page after loading

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to show and hide my Linkedin ID under a certain condition. Both hide() and show() function are in mainjs.js. But from the below code only function hide() is called. And when it makes a call to show() function the JavaScript code is stack at that point. Now how I can call the show() function after loading the html page. Help me please.

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>  Ashik Linkedin </title>
<script src="mainjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1> <a href="http://bd.linkedin.com/pub/muhammad-ashikuzzaman/78/594/940?trk=pub-pbmap">Ashik ( Muhammad Ashikuzzaman ) Linkedin </a> <h1>


<script>
flag=0;
function startTime()
{
    flag++;
    if(flag==60)
    {
        show("Ashik ( Muhammad Ashikuzzaman ) Linkedin");
    }
    if(flag<=70)
    {
        t=setTimeout('startTime()',1000);
    }
}
startTime();
window.hide("Ashik ( Muhammad Ashikuzzaman ) Linkedin"); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just use jquery, it would be much easier. Have a div w/ the linkedin info and then .show() and .hide() methods during the constraints. If not please send a jsfiddle

Comment: @morissette but this is not only the whole code. It is a big code. And have did that code for 10 days. So I can not use jquery. But please can you help with javascript? Because all other function performed with javascript. Is there any way call function after when the page loaded. thanks.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but use `setTimeout(startTime, 1000)` instead of `setTimeout('startTime()', 1000)`.

Comment: Where are your `show()` and `hide()` functions from?

Comment: in main mainjs.js. Thanks.

Comment: The hide is calling but error occurred when show is called again. Please tell me a way to call the function show() @PM77-1

Comment: @morissette I went to jsfiddle. The problem is they have only on javascript panel . But here in my code one portion of javascript is in html page and another portion of javascript is in mainjs.js .

Comment: @PM77-1 is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a bit different approach. Use timer to control the length of time your link is shown. The below assumes that your `show()` and `hide()` functions do work the way you use them.

The below code is **not** tested.

```
window.onload = function() {
      name = "Ashik ( Muhammad Ashikuzzaman ) Linkedin";
      timeToShow = 10000 // 10 seconds to show
      function hideName() {
          hide(name);
      }
      function showThenHide() {         
         window.show(name); 
         setTimeout(hideName, timeToShow);
      };

      showThenHide();
}
```